# How can keep generic type inference when I assign one type with multiple generics with default value?

Tags: typescript, generics

I define a function with multiple generics, and give them default types. For example:

```
function fun<A = any, B = any>(a: A, b: B) {
  return [a, b] as const;
}
```

If I don't assign any types to them, the generics will be infered correctly.

```
let a: number;
let b: string;
const res = fun(a, b);  // [number, string]
```

But if I assign a certain type to part of them, the rest generics will be infered by their default types.

```
let a: number;
let b: string;
const res = fun<number>(a, b);  // [number, any]
```

How can I assign some generics as well as keeping the rest generics inferring themselves?

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABKMAeAgogvIghmATwBpEAhbPQgPgApcAuRdEgI0dIEpEBvAKEUQAnAKZQQgpAG1crALp4AzoggIFUANy8Avr14ATYRAA2uEYiOi8ARkZgQAWxbDBmg8dPDzlljcRrBMGAA5poqYGpCwgpWFCh0VqxWHOoCAPSpiJJ2js4k-oFBsrpuJmYWUHgATLYOTi76hqWe5Ygs1X5QAcGhqhUiCpWx4KjZdbS4layVyWkZWbW5lASyQA)

Comment: I've added a playground link to your question demonstrating the problem. To avoid assigning actual values to the `a` and `b`, I used `declare` to say they're elsewhere, and I had to rename them `a1` and `a2` (etc.) because there were two. Please make any adjustments you like to the playground.

Comment: @8pattern Btw, you don't necessary need to use `as const`. You can defined explicit return type instead https://github.com/captain-yossarian/presentation_devjs/blob/main/3_Tuples_1.ts or variadic tuple types https://github.com/captain-yossarian/presentation_devjs/blob/main/3_Tuples_2.ts

Comment: I'm curious why you want to specify a type argument explicitly like that. If a has a type, there's no need. What's the use case for doing that? I've guessed at one below (broadening a type), but with a specific example we may be able to help you better.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't think this would come up much, typically `a` will have the desired type so there's no reason for explicitly providing a type argument. But in the cases where you want the result to be a different type from `a` (probably a supertype), the solution that comes to mind is to use `as` instead of a type argument.

Here's an example:

```typescript
type NumList = 42 | 67;

declare let a: NumList;
declare let b: string;
const res1 = fun(a, b);  // [NumList, string]

const res2 = fun(a as number, b);  // [number, string]
//                ^^^^^^^^^^
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABKMAeAgogvIghmATwBpEAhbPQgPgApcAuRdEgI0dIEpEBvAKEUQAnAKZQQgpAG1crALp4AzoggIFUANy8Avr15QCAB2GIAciAC2AGRhqKAFgBMiAD6IAbAHZNvACbCIADa4IogBoniMZlY2Gr7+QSFhUIhsiGqCMGAA5poqYLYiCgCMFCh0rBzqAgD01YiSUdZqJOmZWbK6eQXCCk44ZbiKiGAWLMKCFVWItfUj5mMTaVAZ2R0zAhubW4gAenv7B0A)

In general I try to avoid type assertions, but that's effectively what providing the type argument would be anyway, and at least if the type assertion is wildly invalid it'll fail, for instance:

```typescript
declare let a2: string;
const res3 = fun(a2 as number, b);
//               ^^^^^^^^^^^^−−−−−−− error
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABKMAeAgogvIghmATwBpEAhbPQgPgApcAuRdEgI0dIEpEBvAKEUQAnAKZQQgpAG1crALp4AzoggIFUANy8Avr15QCAB2GIAciAC2AGRhqKAFgBMiAD6IAbAHZNvACbCIADa4IogBoniMZlY2Gr7+QSFhUIhsiGqCMGAA5poqYLYiCgCMFCh0rBzqAgD01YiSUdZqJOmZWbK6eQXCCk44ZbiKiGAWLMKCFVWItfUj5mMTaVAZ2R0zAhubW4gAenv7B7p+gcHGSXgOjK3ZuarJhQDMpeB0TrhKcwuTvOvbfwcA-aAJCIQaCgYhxoI4IIgA)